# Homotopy type of connected sum of certain manifolds

Tags: homotopy-theory

For closed n-manifolds M and N with the form $M\simeq M^{n-1}\cup _{f}e^n $,$N\simeq N^{n-1}\cup _{d}e^n$

Why $M\sharp N \simeq (M^{n-1}\vee N^{n-1})\cup _{f+d}e^n$?

Comment: May I suggest consulting http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask. In particular, I wondering why is there a 6-cell in $N$ rather than one of some arbitrary dimension?

Comment: reply to David Roberts:Sorry,it's a mistake which has been amended now.
^ ^!

Comment: Isn't the answer within the definition of connected sum?

Comment: reply to Fernando Muro:May I request an explanation in detail?Thank you!

Comment: @jinch: that question may not be appropriate for a research level forum like this one.